# Can't get last element in arrayList without knowing the length

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class kek2 {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner imeskanera = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> wordlist = new ArrayList <String>();
        
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Type a word: ");
            String word = imeskanera.nextLine();
        
            int lenght =wordlist.size();
            if(word.equals("")) {
                for(int i = 0;i<lenght; i++) {
                    
                System.out.println(wordlist.get(lenght-i));}
                break;
            } 
            wordlist.add(word);
            
            }
        }
    }
```

Im trying to print out the array in reversed order but i get error in `(lenght-i)` part, everything looks fine to me, am'I doing something wrong that Java doesnt allow?

Comment: When `i` is zero, `lenght-i` is equal to `lenght`, which is too big. The last permissible index is `lenght-1`. So `lenght - 1 - i` would make more sense.

Comment: you can reverse a for-loop as well, in your case the head would look like `for (int i = length-1; i >= 0; i--)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be better to limit `while` loop to reading the inputs and when user is done, print the list contents in any desired order.

```java
Scanner imeskanera = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> wordlist = new ArrayList<>();

String word;

System.out.println("Type a word: ");
while(!(word = imeskanera.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
    wordlist.add(word);
    System.out.println("Type a word: ");
}
for (int i = wordlist.size(); i-- > 0;) { // index decremented in condition
    System.out.println(wordlist.get(i));
}
```

Or `ListIterator` may be retrieved using `List::listIterator` and its methods `hasPrevious()` / `previous()` can be used to iterate in reverse direction -- however, the size of list is needed anyway:

```java
for (ListIterator i = wordlist.listIterator(wordlist.size()); i.hasPrevious();) {
    System.out.println(i.previous());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) error in the given code.  Rather than calling `wordlist.get(lenght-i)`, this should be calling `wordlist.get(lenght-i-1)`.

```java
for(int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
    System.out.println(wordlist.get(lenght-i-1));
}
```

An easy way to reason about this is to test the boundary values, and see how they map.  In this case, when `i` is zero, `lenght-i` = `lenght`.  Since lists are zero-indexed, the maximum index that can be used for `List.get` is one less than the length.  Since the goal is to start with the last element of the list, subtracting one from this value (`lenght-i-1`) starts at the correct index.